# Probit Model not working, How to write subscript in r model?

Tags: r

The model:
[image]

The data is in [here](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/capital_markets/allmonth.xls) :
[image]
This model predicts the likely hood of a recession using the yield curve:

- The output, Recessm , is the probability of a recession occurring in
  month t+12 from the viewpoint of information available in month t.
- Spread = 10 Year Treasury Yield - 3 Month Treasury Yield (Bond
  Equivalent Basis)
- α is the constant
- F is the cumulative normal distribution function

Model I have so far:

---

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(wooldridge)
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)
library(ggplot2)
library(np)
setwd("C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop")
```

```
data_allmonth <- read.csv("allmonth.csv"
data_allmonth_probit <- glm(Rec_prob ~ pnorm(Spread), family = bznomial(link = "probit"),  data = data_allmonth)
stargazer(data_allmonth_probit, type = "text")
```

---